# How can I connect my HTML user interface to my Ethereum private chain?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation

I'm trying to learn smart contract development and **test** my contracts.

Before, I used truffle, Metamask and testrpc to test my contracts; and it took care of how to interact my HTML page to the local chain.

Now I'm using "geth" and a private blockchain in Ethereum (I'll explain all the steps shortly). I can deploy my contract using geth. I can interact with the deployed contract using geth console. But I don't know how to connect my HTML file to my blockchain.

**Question 1**: How can I connect my HTML user interface to private blockchain?

**Question 2**: Do I need to use Metamask when I'm using the private chain? If yes, how can I log into Metamask? as the private chain doesn't provide any 12 words phrase that Metamask needs (testrpc provides it).

My contract is very very simple:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract T2{

 uint public k2;
 function T2(){
  k2=32; 
} }
```

The steps I take are as follows:

step 1-

```
 geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain 
"*" --datadir Users/xx/TestChain1 --port "30303" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" 
 --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 123 
 init/Users/xx/CustomGenesis.json
```

step 2-

```
 geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" 
--datadir Users/aydinabadi/TestChain1 --port "30303" --nodiscover --
rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 123 console
```

step 3-

unlock my account on the console and deploy my contract: i.e. I put my contract on remix, run it and copy the content of "Web3 deploy". Then paste it on the geth console.

My .js file is:

```
import "../stylesheets/app.css";
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
 var web3;
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
 }

 var abi=[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"k2","outputs":
 [{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},
 {"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}];

 var ins=web3.eth.contract(abi);
 var instance= ins.at("0x863c7b1600b9312f85501dbc933a862b63dad374");
 var accounts;
 var account;
 var account2;
 window.App = {
 start: function() {
 web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
    return;
  }

  if (accs.length == 0) {
    alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is 
  configured correctly.");
    return;
  }
  accounts = accs;
  account = accounts[0];
  account2 = accounts[1];
  });
   },
  setStatus: function(message) {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerHTML = message;
   },


  k2: function() {
  var spec6 = document.getElementById("spec6");
  var val= instance.k2.call();
  spec6.innerHTML = val.valueOf();

  },
  };
```

and my HTML file is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="en">
<head>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <br><br><button id="send" onclick="App.k2()">Get value</button>
 <span style="padding-left:130px;"> <span style="padding-left:200px;"  
id="spec6"></span>
 <br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are the errors you get in your browser js console?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake Also, I realized when I call my deployed contract variable, it returns 0. In my question, I set "k2=32" but when I call k2 it returns 0 (in the console). Do you know why? thanks

Comment: returns 0 or undefined?

Comment: change in html file  `onClick="k2()"` and in js file  `k2 : function ()` to `function k2()` . Give it a try and tell me the console logs

Comment: sure , comment here the outputs

Comment: btw for your update to the question, you don't need metamask to connect to private chain, even to a testnet or a live net if you have a full node runnig locally, meta mask provide a similar to a light client when you cat run a full node

Comment: I'll post an answer, and will update it with your feed back to the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Question 1** :

You don't need metamask to connect to private chain, even to a testnet or a live net if you have a full node running locally, meta mask provides a similar to a light client when you can't run a full node.

**For Question 2**:

Your onClick function doesn't refer to the function in the app.js since App is not defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have two more questions: 1-how the client sign its transaction without using any wallet? 2- In general, how my HTLM connects itself to the private/live chain? thanks :)

Comment: since you are js file connect to your local node through web3, when you have an account unlocked (default account) , it signs transctions

Comment: did you get the js file connected to the your chain? it's through the rpc port you open, js web3 access the chain through the port

Comment: thanks, for the comments! Yes, everything is running fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can connect Metamask to your localhost or any other network you would like. I posted some easy code examples (In answers) to integrate VanillaJS and Metamask with contracts. Hope it'll help :)

[Sign Data with Metamask and Vanilla JS](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136674/sign-data-with-metamask-and-vanilla-js/136711#136711)

[How to convert contract ABI to HTML interface?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136936/how-to-convert-contract-abi-to-html-interface/136939#136939)