# npm install web3-eth-accounts not creating dist folder

Tags: web3js

As per [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-eth-accounts) `npm install web3-eth-accounts` should create a dist folder.
But i don't see any dist folder being created. Can someone please help me?

Comment: did you run the build command as well? the dist files are made once you build the project

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake npm run-script build-all give following error - npm ERR! path /home/user/web3accounts3/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/web3accounts3/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2017-09-26T20_13_48_288Z-debug.log

Comment: should I be renaming package-lock.json to package.json before running the command to build the project?

Comment: did you go to the [repository](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js)  linked there. I see a dist folder there with a commit message "build files" which are normally gitignored

Comment: The one in the repository does not have this file dist/web3-eth-accounts.js ... there must be an easier way to create, sign and manage accounts through web3 than this, I don't believe I am doing rocket science here am i.

Comment: What type of application are you building? Nodejs one? or a raw html to interact, you may refer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26797/how-can-i-connect-my-html-user-interface-to-my-ethereum-private-chain/26805#26805)

Comment: Thankyou. I had a look at the example you gave. I am building same thing. Trying to execute contract methods through web3 on html. So just to confirm, I don't need to do anything extra to sign the transaction in this setup, right?

Comment: What do you mean by extra?

Comment: By extra I mean, right now I am just calling method on mycontractinstance ... do I have to do anything else in order to sign transaction of that method execution? I have seen examples of rawTx.sign as well as web3js has a sign ojbect ... I don't understand if we have to use it and how?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your project to get the dist folder, which contains the compiled code. So the `npm run-script build-all` will create the dist folder as it's mentioned in the link you referred.

To get a understanding about dist folder, you my refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842691/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dist-directory-in-open-source-projects).

> The shortform dist stands for distributable and refers to a directory
>   where files will be stored that can be directly used by others without
>   the need to compile or minify the source code that is being reused.
>
> Example: If I want to use the source code of a Java library that
>   someone wrote, then you need to compile the sources first to make use
>   of it. But if a library author puts already the precompiled version
>   into the repository, then you can just go ahead. Such an already
>   compiled version is saved into the dist directory.

Comment: npm ERR! path /home/user/web3accounts3/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/web3accounts3/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2017-09-26T20_13_48_288Z-debug.log

Comment: @AntiNatalist if the answer was any help please accept it, or provide your own answer. That's a good practice in SE community.