# Check ethereum balance using text box

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, balances

I want to check ethereum balance of accounts by entering address in text box and click on check balance button it must show the balance in the account.

Please some one help with related links

My second requirement after login into wallet it must automatically display the balance of the account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any details about what you're doing?

Comment: I want to search ethers in address and display the no of ethers in the account

Comment: Have you even try to look for an answer online...?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can do this by using web3, ethereum avascript API, which allows you to interact with an ethereum chain either via by RPC to a full node connected to the chain or by injected Web  3 (with metamask like plugin).The high level architecture would look like,

[image]

What you have to do is build your html interface, load a js file with web3 module imported and you can call `eth.getBalance(account_address)` with the *onclick* enevt of the button and display the return value.

If you want it to be displayed when the user logs in, send the same call at the page loading time (document-ready) and get the return value.

You may refer [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26797/how-can-i-connect-my-html-user-interface-to-my-ethereum-private-chain/26805#26805), posts [here](https://www.mobilefish.com/developer/blockchain/blockchain_quickguide_web3_gui.html) and [here](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/ethereum-for-web-developers-890be23d1d0c) as well.