# How to create accounts using a light client tool?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, myetherwallet, metamask

My question is related to this:

[MetaMask and Ethereum Private Chain (for test)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28200/metamask-and-ethereum-private-chain-for-test)

The difference is that here I want to use a light client who can create its address, public and secret keys; and store them locally.

---

Assume I have a private blockchain on computer A. I have defined some money in the Genesis block for myself.

I'd like other nodes via online tools, e.g. MetaMask and MyEtherWallet to:

1- create their public/secret keys and address.

2- create an account on the private chain.

3- Then I (computer A) can give them some Ether.

4- Now, they can deploy their smart contract to the private chain.

**Question**: How can other nodes create accounts in the above setting and interact with the computer A?

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries in javascript to generate a wallet programatically [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) and [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet).