# How to connect a computer to a private chain using Wifi and MetaMask

Tags: contract-deployment, metamask, nodes

I've set up a private chain on computer A. I'm using geth and the following two command lines:

```
geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" 
--datadir Users/TestChain --port "30303" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"  --
nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 123 init 
/Users/CustomGenesis.json
```

---

```
geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" 
--datadir Users/TestChain --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi 
"db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 123 console
```

I want to connect another node/computer B to this chain, so it can send transactions/contracts to it. On both machines, I have installed Metamask.

For machine A, I Googled my public IP. Let's call it IP_A. Then on machine B, in MetaMask, I created a custom RPC as follows: IP_A:8545

But, it cannot connect to computer A, it says:

```
   connecting to unknown private network.
```

and nothing happens after that.

**Question**: How can I resolve the above issue? How can I connect two computers using wifi and metamask?

**Edit**: Please see my other question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28200/metamask-and-ethereum-private-chain-for-test/28367#28367), I've answered this question as well. Thanks to @Achala Dissanayake.

Comment: try `--rpcaddr "[A's ip address]"  ` instead of  `--rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"  --`

Comment: make sure B is also connected to the same wifi network, if you are using private ip addresses

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake Thanks. I tried that but it's not working. I even tried to use public IP.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can use public if you are inside a NAT. Is A's ip address starts with 192.168....? and B is also in the same network and have 192.168.... address?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake both IP addresses start with 192.42

Comment: does a ping from B to A work in the console?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake great hint: No it doesn't, time out. Does it mean I'm not using a correct IP address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66980/discussion-between-achala-dissanayake-and-adrian-ad).

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake I cannot reply on the chat room. It's disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,

since you `ping` to the computer A from computer B gives a time-out, the error of `connecting to unknown private network` probably due to computer being unable to find the network specified in Metamask as `IP_A:8545`.

Then you need to change use `--rpcaddr "[A's ip address]"` instead of `--rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"` to make the node accessible by B.

Resolving these will fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--chainId` flag and set it to the same thing as your `--networkId` value. These two things have a different meaning for some clients, but MetaMask requires you set them both to the same value.