# How to connect metamask private network node on VM

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, nodes

Hello i'm currently I have my chain running inside my virtual machine (with Ubuntu 16.04) and my PC (running Windows 10). NodeJS is running a server which i can access from http://192.168.0.108:3000/. [image: metamask on PC] Metamask running on firefox inside the VM can actually connect to the network.[image: metamsk running on VM] Have tried what this post suggests( [MetaMask and Access Ethereum Private Chain from other PC in the same network (for test)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28200/metamask-and-access-ethereum-private-chain-from-other-pc-in-the-same-network-fo) ) but had no luck so far. 
This is my starting node command`geth --datadir ~/eth-dev/ --identity 'nodo maquina local' --verbosity 4 --ipcdisable --rpc --port 30304 --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --syncmode "full" --networkid 7051872 --targetgaslimit 16233158 console`

Comment: check if the 8545 is open in your vm or map it

Comment: i have opened it using  'sudo ufw allow 22', but still not working

Comment: i mean,  'sudo ufw allow 8545'

Comment: try to explecite the port using -rpcport or use another port than 8545

Comment: i have tried setting it to port 7373 and the issue persists, metamask inside VM can connect but my PC cannot

Comment: if anyone cares, i connected metamask on my pc directly to one of my nodes on AWS and it is now working.

Comment: @RobertoC. If your VM is NAT and you cannot change to bridged you have to enable port forwarding and map host port 9999 to 8545 in the VM. Then when you connect to host_ip:9999 it will redirect to vm_ip:8545.

Answer (score 1):

Force the port 8545 to rpc, e.g.

geth --datadir ~/eth-dev/ --identity 'nodo maquina local' --verbosity 4 --ipcdisable --rpc **--rpcport "8545"** --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --syncmode "full" --networkid 7051872 --targetgaslimit 16233158 console

Answer (score 0):

Open virtualbox -> right click on your machine -> settings -> Network -> Enable network adapter -> select bridge adapter and you can now set a port forwarder from your virtualmachine to your localhost.

Then, try to connect to `http://localhost:8545` and that should work like a charm.

Comment: The only way i can configure port forwarding is with NAT adapter and that is no the conf i want to use.

Comment: Which conf do you want to use then?

Comment: I'd like to stay on bridged mode

Comment: since VM node is connected to other nodes running on AWS