# Configuring geth so that it can only connect to my private local blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, peers, connections

Basically I would like to know how to configure geth so that it can only connect to my private ethereum blockchain that is hosted on another machine?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: will this be helpful https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/28200/16301

Comment: That would be one solution using MetaMask. However, I would like to use geth instead of MetaMask and configure it so that it can only connect to my private bc and no others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geth can only connect to one blockchain. Unless you pass a different port and a different path for the data directory.

to connect to your private blockchain just get the enodes addresses and the machine external ip (ports should be opened) and pass it in geth

for example

```
geth --datadir ~\.space --networkid 1337  --bootnodes=enode://42aa0f3f526ed619032e0c1b3526e15b20df4dc0229f9a6f991e6f31d86561dfb2d5d14d36dcaa29867a31709ab0d7e0fc868eb6d7dde344116318386aeb87d5@YOUR_EXTERNAL_IP:30304 --rpc --rpcapi admin,db,eth,net,web3,personal,txpool --shh --ws --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Comment: I get this step. But what I would like to achieve is to configure geth so that it can connect to one and only one blockchain, which is my private one. In other words, I don't want the following situation to happen: that I start geth and connect to one blockchain and the next time I start geth again I connect to another blockchain. Basically, what I would like is to configure Geth on my computer so that it can only connect to one chain and one chain only, which is my private blockchain.

Comment: well you put the starting script in a ... sh script and start it only from there. other option is to fork geth and put some constraints there..