# Transactions on Ethereum private network using the MetaMask Ropsten test connection?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, metamask, ropsten

I have 4 accounts on my private blockchain ethereum network and one of the account has balance of 10000000000000000000 and other accounts have zero balance each.

When I connect to this network from MetaMask, using Ropsten Test network, should the same balance from private ethereum network be reflected in the MetaMask wallet having same number of accounts from my private ethereum network. And can i transact between these accounts *(from account1 to account2, as these are created using commands on server)* using the MetaMask wallet?

If i create the new account on metamask, should that account be reflected on my private ethereum network?

How should i transfer my existing balance from one account to other?

Regards,
Jagdish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not particularly clear but:

- A private key maps to an address. Ropsten/Mainnet/Your Private network use the same codebase. A valid private key on one network is valid on all of them.
- You can not transfer Ether across networks (obviously) and whilst the transaction signature for an Ether transfer could be replayed on any/all networks (subject to appropriate nonces etc) you would have to manually submit the transaction to each network.
- Transactions need to be mined by miners. If you mine a tx on your private network that is completely independent of the same tx bytecode being mined into a block on another network.
- If you have given yourself millions of Ether on your private network (in your genesis file) submitting the same tx bytecode to a different network would likely fail as the account (whilst valid) would not have enough Ether on the other network.

EDIT

- You can use Metamask to connect to a private network as outlined in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28202).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, for sharing the knowledge. Let me try to ask it in a different way, see if it makes sense. 
I want to transfer account balance from one account to other on my private ethereum network (not connecting to outside public or private network). Can i achieve this using the MetaMask, that is to transfer the account balance within the private network.I want to utilize the balance (to be transferred) which was earned through mining on my private ethereum network.

Comment: Yes. Answer updated.

Comment: Ok. well, so i connected to my private ethereum network using the metamask and it is connected using the Ropsten test network.
now issue is the account balance which is there in account1 (of my private ethereum network) is not getting reflected in the Metamask wallet.

Comment: May be a metamask issue, may be an issue on your end with your setup. Sadly StackExchange is not for step by step individual troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, for your expert thoughts and ideas. I appreciate your help.. I will take it up further!!