# Is it possible to use MetaMask for a private consortium on Ethereum?

Tags: metamask, testnets, ropsten, rinkeby, kovan

Assuming we create a private consortium chain over Ethereum and we want to use MetaMask for storing the keys and signing transactions to send the tokens belonging to this private consortium. Apparently, MetaMask only support the Ethereum mainnet along with three following testnets:

- Ropsten
- Kovan
- Rinkeby

So, is it possible to use MetaMask for holding the keys and signing the transactions to send the tokens belonging to this private consortium that has been created over the Ethereum? And if yes, how to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible:

1. Configure Metamask to connect to a node that synchronizes with your private network
2. Configure Metamask to use correct chain ID for your private network when constructing transactions
3. Configure Metamask to use correct network ID for your private network, probably the same as chain ID

Comment: Thank you, (1) Is there any step by step tutorial to show the steps to do in more details? (2) Does it mean for every time that I want to sign a new transaction by MetaMask, I need to set my IP address? (3) Is everybody able to see the name of our consortium in MetaMask, Or a permission is needed to see it like other testnests ? (4) Are the steps the same as it is explained in this answer? [Link to answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28202/23024) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
You have to setup the custom RPC, the last option in the network
then enter your ip address and rpc port in "NEW RPC URL" feild
eg. http://18.136.***.*:7777
(protocol://hostname:port) and do remember to allow the rpc for everyone if you want that metamask should detect the network form any system.

Comment: Thank you, (1) Is there any step by step tutorial to show the steps to do in more details? (2) Does it mean for every time that I want to sign a new transaction by MetaMask, I need to set my IP address? (3) Is everybody able to see the name of our consortium in MetaMask, Or a permission is needed to see it like other testnests ? Thanks