# Connecting to Geth private network from Metamask using RPC URL

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, dapp-development, rpc

I have created a private chain in Geth which is running in `machine1`. I want to connect to the private chain running in `machine1` from `machine2's` Metamask using rpc. `machine1` and `machine2` are connected to the same Wifi network.

The IP address of `machine1` is 192.168.0.103 and I am opening port number 8501 for RPC connections.

The following are the flags that I have used to start Geth in `machine1`:

```
geth --datadir "C:\Users\smuth\Desktop\GETH DAPP POA\node1" --port 30311 --http --http.addr "192.168.0.103" --http.port 8501 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api "personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner" --networkid 1515 console --ipcdisable --nat extip:192.168.0.103
```

I tried using the rpc url http://192.168.0.103:8501 and chain ID as 1515 in Metamask of `machine2`. But Metamask doesn't connect and displays the error : "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"
The console log of Metamask displays a timed out HTTP POST request to the RPC URL (http://192.168.0.103:8501)

A similar question is posted here:
[MetaMask and Access Ethereum Private Chain from other PC in the same network (for test)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28200/metamask-and-access-ethereum-private-chain-from-other-pc-in-the-same-network-fo)

But the solutions for the above question does'nt work for me.

What could be changed to make this connection work?

Answer (score 0):

Geth currently only allows RPC requests from localhost. I made something like this, although it would require nginx.
https://github.com/TennisBowling/geth-nginx 
Then you would be able to access it without setting a port.

Comment: Thanks for this approach @TennisBowling but I found a more easier way. The firewall of machine1 was blocking connections to the port 8501 so I changed the inbound, outbound rules for the port 8501 and it is working!

Comment: Please watch out with this @UmaMuthukumar . DO NOT USE GETH ACCOUNTS. bots find open rpc's and then just drain geth accounts. use metamask connected to geth.