# How to convert contract ABI to HTML interface?

Tags: solidity

How to convert ABI to HTML interface? For example:

https://oneclickdapp.com/

https://abi.hashex.org/

I want to be able to interact with my contract.

Comment: I answered, let me know if it helped and please make sure you ask more detailed questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with your contract using VanillaJS, you first must include:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>`

Than, **if you have Metamask installed** in your browser you can start with this code example I wrote:

```
 if (window.ethereum) {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    window.web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];
    const response = await fetch("ABI.json");
    const json = await response.json();
    window.contract = new window.web3.eth.Contract(json.abi, "0xCONTRACT_ADDRESS");
}
else{
    console.log("No metamask")
}
```

In the end `window.contract` will have the functions you need. Don't miss the `"0xCONTRACT_ADDRESS"` that you need to replace by your deployed contract and `ABI.json` that you need to have in your file system.

**Note:** You should run your html using http server or Metamask wouldn't inject `window.ethereum`